# Create list with looping

Tags: r, list, if-statement, for-loop

I have a i times j (`ixj`) dummy-matrix for rating events of companies, with i dates and j different companies. On a day where a rating occurs rating `[i,j]=1` and 0 otherwise.

I want to create a list, which contains 4 sublist (1 for each of the 4 companies). Each sublist states the row numbers of the rating event of the specific company.

This is my code:

```
r<-list(); i=1;j=2;
for(j in 1:4){
    x<-list()
    for(i in 100){
        if(rating[i,j]!=0){
        x<-c(x,i)
        i=i+1
        }
        else{i=i+1}
    }
    r[[j]]<-x
    j=j+1
}
```

It is somehow not working, and I really can not figure out where the bug is. The x sublists are always empty. Could somebody help?

Thanks a lot!

Here is an example rating matrix:

```
 rating<-matrix(data = 0, nrow = (100), ncol = 4, dimnames=list(c(1:100), c(1:4)));
 rating[3,1]=1;rating[7,1]=1;rating[20,1]=1;rating[75,1]=1;
 rating[8,2]=1;rating[40,2]=1;rating[50,2]=1;rating[78,2]=1;
 rating[1,3]=1;rating[4,3]=1;rating[17,3]=1;rating[99,3]=1;
 rating[10,4]=1;rating[20,4]=1;rating[30,4]=1;rating[90,4]=1;
```

Comment: Every time you encounter `x<-list()` inside that j-indexed-loop, any previous value in `x` will be erased. You also should NOT change i inside the i-indexed-loop. The for-function will do it for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I dont think this is the bug though: I want the x sublist to get overwritten, because in the second for loop all rating events of company j are stored in x. Then I add x to the list r, and start again for company j+1 (so x gets overwritten, but that does not matter, because its stored in r[[j]].

Comment: Post a small subset of `rating` using  `dput`

Comment: just did above, also adjusted the code to that matrix, so you can jost copy everything. thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(data = sample(c(0, 1), 16, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4,
            dimnames = list(date = 1:4, company = letters[1:4]))
m
#     company
# date a b c d
#    1 0 1 1 1
#    2 1 0 0 1
#    3 0 1 1 0
#    4 1 1 0 1

lapply(as.data.frame(m), function(x){
  which(x == 1)
})

# $a
# [1] 2 4
# 
# $b
# [1] 1 3 4
# 
# $c
# [1] 1 3
# 
# $d
# [1] 1 2 4
```

**Update**
Or more compact (thanks to @flodel!):

```
lapply(as.data.frame(m == 1), which)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much Henrik! I should learn to use functions instead of loops :)

Comment: more compact: `lapply(as.data.frame(m) == 1, which)`

Comment: @flodel, Thank you for your comment. I don't manage to get the same result with your code; instead of one element per company, I get a list with 16 elements. Maybe I miss something obvious here...

Comment: interesting... make it `lapply(as.data.frame(m == 1), which)` then :-) Sorry I did not test before commenting.

Comment: @flodel, I added your alternative to the answer to make it more visible. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Hi @flodel and @Henrik, you helped me so well yesterday, could I ask you one more question (trying to figure this out since hours again..) since you seem to know functions really well. I have this code now: `myfunction2 <- function(y){
  x<-cds1.R
  y <- y[y>0]
  if(!is.null(y)) 
    x[-y]
  else 
    x
}

rl<-lapply(rowind.all,myfunction2)`

Comment: cds1.R is a matrix with 1552rows and 153 columns. rowind.all is a list containing 153 other lists, where each of these 153 lists contains some index numbers (between 1 and 1552). What I am trying to do with the function: I want to create a list rl, which contains i=153 sublists. The sublists should contain all values from cds1.R[,i], except those listed in rowind.all[i].

Comment: Sorry, I hope you can help me, otherwise I make a real forum request... thank you!

Comment: @user3428319, Thanks for your comment. It seems to me that it is better that you post a new question. Because you are new to SO, you may have a look [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) to learn about creating small, reproducible examples. People are generally much more happy to help if you post a tiny dummy data set to play with. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

(Leave for-loops behind.) If ratings really is a matrix or even if its a dataframe, then why not use rowSums:

```
r <- rowSums(rating) # accomplished the stated task more effectively.

# simple example: 
> rating <- matrix( rbinom(100, 1,prob=.5), 10)
> rating
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    0     1
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     1
 [3,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    1     0
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     1
 [5,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0     0
 [6,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    1     0
 [7,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     0
 [8,]    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    1    1     0
 [9,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
[10,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0     1
> rowSums(rating)
 [1] 5 4 5 4 6 7 5 5 7 4
> rowSums(as.data.frame(rating))
 [1] 5 4 5 4 6 7 5 5 7 4
```

If it needs to be a list then just wrap as.list() around it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but I need the row numbers of when the rating occurs, not the number of rating events.